# Cannot able to call this API - AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, api

I am trying to call this SMS API from [2factor](http://2factor.in)

This is the code, I am getting CORS issue

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://2factor.in/API/V1/293832-67745-11e5-88de-5600000c6b13/SMS/991991199/AUTOGEN",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {},
  "data": "{}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Code can be found here - 
[Sample Code](https://2fa.api-docs.io/v1/send-sms-otp/sending-sms-otp-auto-generated-otp)
 How to make http get request with CORS enabled

Even if I use 'jsonp', I am getting

> unexpected token ':'

How to solve this

Comment: Make sure that your jQuery version is 1.5+ (where the `crossDomain` option was added)

Comment: are you sure you dont get the unexpected token error somewhere else?

Comment: yes i am so sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in you sample request, please check this first.

1. Phone number needs to be **10 digits**, you only pass **9 digits**
2. **Invalid** API key